# How should I set a searchbox in commandbar item?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to set an Autosuggestbox inside the commandbar item in a UWP application. I would like to create a search box on the style of the Windows 10 Weather App.

What I would like to have:
[commandbar from Windows 10 weather app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpetO.png)

What I have:
[my commandbar item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMnvk.png)

This is the xaml code I'm using:

```
        <CommandBar x:Name="cmd_bar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Save Location"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="Search"/>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200px" Background="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            x:Name="search_box"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>

    </CommandBar>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default style of commandbar, the content part is set to the left, so when you add Autosuggestbox in its content, the Autosuggestbox will be placed on the left and the more button is pinned to the right. So it's better to set a **two-column** Grid and put your command bar in the first column and the Autosuggestbox in the second column. For example:

**Update:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CommandBar x:Name="cmd_bar" Grid.Column="0">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Save Location"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="Search"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="{ThemeResource CommandBarBackground}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding ElementName=cmd_bar,Path=ActualHeight}">
        <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200px" Background="Gray" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="search_box"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Or** if you still want the search box is inside the commandBar, you can add the Autosuggestbox in the style of commandBar. There is a button named MoreButton represents the moreButton, you can add a stackPanel which Orientation is Horizontal then add the moreButton and Autosuggestbox in it.

.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CommandBarStyle1" TargetType="CommandBar">
        ......
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CommandBar">
                    ......
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Button x:Name="MoreButton" ......>
                            <FontIcon x:Name="EllipsisIcon" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="20" Glyph="&#xE10C;" Height="{ThemeResource AppBarExpandButtonCircleDiameter}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Button>
                        <AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200px" Background="Gray" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="search_box"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    ......
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<CommandBar Style="{StaticResource CommandBarStyle1}" x:Name="cmd_bar" Grid.Column="0">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Add" Label="Save Location"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Delete" Label="Delete Location" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh"/>
    <AppBarButton Icon="Find" Label="Search"/>
</CommandBar>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. That code you post sets the items in the correct position but I'm not able to aling all the items and to make the search box look as 
if it where inside the same command bar. With that code the search box is outside the command bar so the command bar background doesn't apply to the search box.

Comment: I have updated my answer, about "the command bar background doesn't apply to the search box.", you can set the background of  search box as the same as CommandBar's by using `Background="{ThemeResource CommandBarBackground}"`. Then if you still want the AutoSuggestBox inside the CommandBar, you can change the CommandBar's default style like above.

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete styles..

```cs
<Style x:Key="NewAppBarButtonSearchStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="48" />

        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                    <Grid
                        x:Name="Root"
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
                        MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
                        Margin="0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="5">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="LabelOnRightStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}">
                            <AutoSuggestBox
                                PlaceholderText="Search"
                                MinWidth="150"
                                Margin="0,-20,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                x:Name="TextLabel"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Margin="2,0,2,6"
                                FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                FontSize="12"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                                TextAlignment="Center"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock
                            x:Name="OverflowTextLabel"
                            Margin="12,0,12,0"
                            Padding="0,5,0,7"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                            FontSize="15"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"
                            TextAlignment="Left"
                            TextTrimming="Clip"
                            TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullSize" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelOnRight">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="12,14,0,14" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TextAlignment">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Left" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="8,15,12,17" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="LabelCollapsed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MinHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                               
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource AppBarButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="GameControllerInputMode">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Find the AutocompleteBox

```cs
var search = this.searchAppBar.FindChildOfType<AutoSuggestBox>();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).